# Density of a set around $0$ and on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73262/proving-that-mn-sqrt2-is-dense-in-r), we prove that $\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ by proving that is it dense around $0$.

Why is that enough to prove that it is dense on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a direct, nice and simple demonstration of the final result: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/90180/40061 . The key point is the fact that S is an additive group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because then you can take the integer multiples $k(a+b\sqrt2)=ka+kb\sqrt2$ to fill the rest of the line.

Comment: But how are you sure that this will fill (i.e. be dense on) __all__ the line ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon If $a+b\sqrt 2\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\setminus\{0\}$, then the integer multiples fill all intervals of lenght larger than $\varepsilon$.