# Set of points where Fourier mode converges

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

How one can prove
$$|\{x\in[0,2\pi] : \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{inx} \ \ \ \text{exists}\}| = 0$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Any hints please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\{m \alpha, m \in \mathbb Z\}$is dense in $[0,1]$ for $\alpha$ irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463492/m-alpha-m-in-mathbb-z-is-dense-in-0-1-for-alpha-irrational)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{e^{inx}\}$ converges. Then what is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{inx}\bigr)?
$$
What does it tell you about $x$?

Comment: Thank you! So that limit would be $0$ and this implies that $e^{ix}=1$ therefore $x\in \{2\pi n : n \in Z\}$ and the latter set has measure $0$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.