# Can finite sums of two numbers come arbitrarily close to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Given two real numbers $a$ and $b$, define an *$a$-$b$-sum* as a finite sum of $a$'s and $b$'s, i.e. a sum:

$$m\cdot a + n\cdot b$$
where $m,n$ are non-negative integers.

**Is there a pair of numbers $a<0$ and $b>0$, such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $a$-$b$-sum $S \in (0,\epsilon)$?**

The claim is obviously untrue if $a$ and $b$ are integers, since in that case the sum is also integer so there is no $S \in (0,1)$.

It is also untrue if $a$ and $b$ are rationals, since in that case the sum is always an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{pq}$ (where $p,q$ are the denominators of $a,b$ respectively) so there is no $S\in (0,\frac{1}{pq})$.

Is there a pair of irrational numbers that makes the claim true?

Comment: I might be misreading something, but since the sum is finite isn't it equal to $ma + nb$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @Ennar you are right. I simplified the question accordingly.

Comment: More reading and generalizations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker's_theorem) or [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html).

Comment: This fact is relevant: The set $C$ of integer linear combinations $ma+nb$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ and so is either discrete cyclic or dense. Which case holds depends on whether $\alpha:=\inf (C \cap \mathbb R^+)=0$ or not.

Comment: A great point, @lhf!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=-1$ .

From Kronecker's Theorem there is a positive integer $c$ such that :
$$\{c\sqrt{2}\} < \epsilon $$ (This case of the theorem can be proved by a simple pigeon-hole argument )

Now simply take the following $(a,b)$-sum :

$$c \cdot a + \lfloor c\sqrt{2} \rfloor \cdot b=c\sqrt{2}-\lfloor c\sqrt{2} \rfloor=\{c\sqrt{2} \}<\epsilon$$ as wanted .

Comment: by $\{x\}$ you mean the fractional part of $x$?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, yes.

Comment: Yes. A pigeonhole argument works whenever $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$. For the specific pair $\sqrt2$ and $-1$ you can also take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/73268/11619). Mariano's or lhf's answer in the same thread gives an argument that IIRC works whenever $a/b$ is irrational.