# Approximation of integer by multiple of irrational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Obviously, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exist $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that$$|\sqrt{2}-\frac{n}{m}|<\epsilon \; \textrm{.}$$
Is it also true that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exist $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that$$|\sqrt{2}m-n|<\epsilon \; \textrm{?}$$
If so, does it also hold for transcendental numbers?

Comment: In some sense, transcendental numbers can be approximated BETTER by rational numbers than irrational numbers (see Liouville's approxmation therem).

Comment: @Peter you mean algebraic?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Of course ...

Comment: For $\sqrt2$ specifically you can also look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73262/11619). Some discussion about the general case is also there, Mariano's answer in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation

it is shown that every irrational number $\alpha$ satisfies

$$|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^2}$$

for infinite many pairs $(p,q)$. If you multiply with $q$, you see that the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for