# How can I prove that the sequence $a_n = 1/\cos(n),$ where $n$ is a natural number, is unbounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Obviously, the function $1/\cos(x)$ is unbounded. There are singularities at $x_k =k\pi + \pi/2$. Are there natural numbers that come arbitrarily close to $x_k$?
Or is there any other way to prove that the assumption $|1/\cos(n)|< C$ leads to a contradiction?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73262/proving-that-mn-sqrt2-is-dense-in-r).

Comment: This follows from [Weyl's Equidistribution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) and the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: Indeed that should solve the problem. But Dirichlet's approximation theorem (thanks to Xander) should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the continued fraction of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, which is infinite since $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$:
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}=\left[1; 1, 1, 3, 31, 1, 145, 1, 4, 2, 8, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 41,\ldots\right] $$
There are infinite convergents of such continued fraction with an odd denominator:
$$ \frac{2}{1},\frac{11}{7},\frac{344}{219},\frac{51819}{32989},\frac{52174}{33215},\frac{260515}{165849},\ldots$$
and their numerators give natural numbers $n$ such that $\cos(n)$ is closer and closer to zero.
Indeed, from
$$ \left|q_n\frac{\pi}{2}-p_n\right|\leq \frac{1}{q_n} $$
and the Lipschitz-continuity of $\cos$ we get
$$ \left|\cos(p_n)\right|=\left|\cos(p_n)-\cos(\pi q_n/2)\right|\leq\frac{1}{q_n}\approx\frac{\pi}{2p_n} $$
so $\left\{\frac{1}{\cos(n)}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is unbounded since $\{p_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is unbounded.

Comment: Because $\pi/4 = \arctan(1) = 1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9 -+ $ I can create such a sequence to approximate $\pi/2 $, where the denominator is odd.

Comment: @SwanhildBernstein: This is not granted to provide values of n such that cos(n) is arbitrarily close to 0. You have to consider accurate rational approximations to make the trick work.

Comment: No, but it gives the quotients $p_n/q_n - \pi/2$ getting smaller and smaller, if $|p_n/q_n -\pi/2|< 1$ then $|p_n - q_n\pi/2| < 1/q_n .$

Comment: @SwanhildBernstein:  not enough to ensure $\cos(p_n)\to 0$, however.

Comment: How do you get "accurate rational apprimations"?

Comment: By considering the convergents of a continued fraction, ie the best rational approximations.

Comment: To do what? Twice the numerators of the partial sums of Mengoli series still do not work.

Comment: But I can use mean value theorem $|\cos(p_n)| = |\cos(p_n) - \cos(q_n\pi/2)|\leq |\sin(\xi_n)||p_n-q_n\pi/2| \leq |p_n - q_n\pi/2|\leq 1/q_n.$ That need not to be fasted way, but it should work?

Comment: @SwanhildBernstein: the last inequality does not hold for generic approximations, only if $p_n/q_n$ is a convergent of $\pi/2$. That's the relevance of the continued fraction shown above.