# About usual topology On $\mathbb{R}$ and $S=\{a+b \cdot\sqrt{2}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

How can I find interior of $S$, exterior of $S$, Boundary of $S$, limit points of $S$ ,isolated points of $S$ and closure of $S$?

My try:

I found that  $ Int(S)=\phi$ because if $m \in S$ there doesn't exist open set $U \in$ usual topolgy of $R$  such that $m \in U \subseteq S$.

But sadly I was not capable of finding the rest of them.

My motivation to problem:
Yesterday at night I was searching about proofs of irrationality of $e$ and I found pdf file that give outline which is built as exercises for proof using topology...one exercise of them is:

Prove that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ iff $0$ is an isolated point of $\{a+b\alpha:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

So for this reason I become curious about finding interior of S, exterior of S, Boundary of S, limit points of S ,isolated points of S and closure of S (note:I choose $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ in $S$).

The pdf file is:
https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Irrationale.pdf

Comment: $\overline S=\mathbb R, Ext(S)= Int(S)=\emptyset, \partial S=\mathbb R, S'=\mathbb R$.

Comment: An additive subgroup of $\Bbb{R}$ either discrete or dense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are my arguments correct about limit points of $A=${$m+n\sqrt 2:m,n\in \mathbb Z$}?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662939/are-my-arguments-correct-about-limit-points-of-a-mn-sqrt-2m-n-in-mathbb-z)

Comment: @SouravGhosh 

This obviously doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @geetha290krm 

I asked how to find them not just what are they equal to.

Comment: I think the linked post is enough to answer your question.Please read carefully.

Comment: @SouravGhosh

Where is the explanation of how to find boundary points or isolated points of $S$ in the question you suggested?

and the question is about someone discussing his arguments(that don't answer my question) and ask whether they are false or true .

And finally thank you for your try to help by suggesting similar question.