# Which of the following is true about the numbers $m+n\sqrt 2\;$ ($m,\,n$ are integers)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Which of the following is true about set $A$?

$A=\{m+n \cdot 2^{1/2} : m, n \text{ are integers}\}$

1. $A$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.
2. $A$ has only countable number of limit point in $\mathbb R$.
3. $A$ has no limit point in $\mathbb R$.
4. Only irrational number is limit point of $A$.

please explain.

Comment: The answer is 1).

Comment: yes the answer is 1) but I want explanation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73262/proving-that-mn-sqrt2-is-dense-in-mathbb-r

Comment: Please use mathjax. See my edit of your question.

Comment: Do you know the result about the structure of subgroups of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

1. is true. Implying the others are false.

For $x\in \Bbb R$ let {$x$} be the fractional part of $x.$ That is, if $z\in \Bbb Z$ and $z\le x<z+1$ then {$x$}$=x-z.$  Let $F(x)=\{ n${$x$}$: n\in \Bbb N\}. $ If $x$ is irrational then $F(x)$ is dense in $[0,1].$ There are many ways to prove this. I recommend the link in the comment to the Q by @Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: I don't disagree with your proof, but I'm genuinely curious about why 2 is false. Isn't A itself countable?

Comment: @harwiltz . $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ so every $r\in\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $A$...... $\Bbb Q$ is another example of a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R$

Comment: thanks a lot. That's pretty neat. I also interpreted 2 as there are countably many limit points of R contained in A.