# Is $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$? I know this should be easy, but I am at a loss right now.

Comment: It might be easier to show that the $\mathbb Z \alpha \pmod 1$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @QuangHoang those are equivalent statements.

Comment: Yes they exactly equivalent. What I meant is that attending to $(0,1)$ only might be a little easier.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73262/11619). My answer there is specific to $\alpha=\sqrt2$, but Mariano Suárez-Álvarez posted an answer that works for all irrationals.

Comment: Use [KAT](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html).

Comment: @TheThinWhistler: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189397/why-is-this-quotient-space-not-hausdorff/189402#189402) I gave an elementary proof that $\{nr\bmod1:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha$ is an [additive subgroup](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Real_Numbers_is_Discrete_or_Dense) of $\mathbb R$. And the additive subgroups of the real numbers are either discrete or dense.

If $G$ was discrete, it would exist $0 \neq \beta \in \mathbb R$ and $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ such that

$$\begin{cases}
1 &= b \beta\\
\alpha &= a \beta
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $\alpha = a/b$ would be rational. A contradiction.

Hence $G$ is dense.

Comment: What if $a=1,b=0$? Since this answer is downvoted , please note that I didn't downvote.

Comment: Aren't you assuming exactly what OP has to prove - that there are only those two options

Comment: how do I know the additive subgroups are either discrete or dense?

Comment: @PNDas I was too quick... Answer updated.

Comment: @TheThinWhistler See [Subgroup of Real Numbers is Discrete or Dense](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Real_Numbers_is_Discrete_or_Dense).

Comment: @TheThinWhistler if the group has a limit point $x$, subtract everything by $x$ then $0$ is an limit point. It should be easy to show then that the group is dense in a neighborhood of $0$, hence dense everywhere.

Comment: Still the updated version doesn't seem to clarify the situation. Why does the expression follow from the discreteness?

Comment: If $G$ is discrete, $G= \beta \mathbb Z$ for $0 \neq \beta \in \mathbb R$. And $1=1+0 \alpha$, $\alpha = 0 + 1 \alpha$ both belong to $G$.

Comment: Still, these are assumptions that one, who asks this question, does not necessarily know

Comment: @kesa Sure. Proves of a result may depend on the theorems that you apply. This result about additive subgroups of the reals is pretty *well known* though.

Comment: I'm am aware of that, my point is that you seem to ignore that someone who asks this question might not

Comment: got it now. it should have been easy from the start.